# Use Vertica Database for OLTP data?

Tags: vertica

Can Vertica Database be used for OLTP data?
And if so what are the pros and cons on doing this? 
 Looking for a Vertica vs Oracle fight :)
Since Oracle license is so costly, would Vertica do it job for a better price ?
 thx all

Answer (score 5):

Using Vertica as a transactional database is a bad idea. It's designed to be a data warehousing tool. Essentially, it reads and writes data in an optimized fashion. Lots of transactions? That's not what it is designed to do.

I would recommend that you look into VoltDB. Michael Stonebreaker who is the force behind Vertica founded that company as well. His basic philosophy is that Oracle, SQL Server, et al do not do well for high performance since they are designed to do everything. The future is having databases designed for specific tasks.

So he had some concepts for a data warehousing which became Vertica. For transactional databases, there's VoltDB. Not owned by HP, for the record.

For the record, I haven't used VoltDB. From what I know, it isn't as mature as Vertica is as a solution but it looks like it has a ton of promise.

Comment: Thx Geoff, <br/> True Vertica design is not for OLTP use, by using it in OLTP you take away it's WOS and ROS extras witch makes it different form others.<br/> The strange part is that still it makes everything much better then OLTP RDBMS , so far the speed is great .<br/> As for VoltDB like you said is still not mature wicth makes it hard to present to clients.<br/> But is a DB to keep my eyes on :).<br/>. I am going to try to implement Vertica along with other OLTP RDBMS , maybe with a 5 years plan we might get a good return from it in $$$ wise !!

Answer (score 3):

HP Vertica is a column store database.  The nature of the way that data is organised within a column store does not lend itself to rapid writes.

HP Vertica gets around this by having a WOS (Write Optimised Store) and ROS (Read Optimised Store which is file based).

Data is moved out of the WOS into the ROS fairly rapidly and the ROS itself has a "merge up" process that takes small ROS files and merges them together to form larger and therefore more easily scanned files.

If you tried to use Vertica for OLTP then what would happen would be that you'd get loads of ROS containers and possibly hit the default limit of 1024 ROS containers very quickly.

If you fronted the store with some form a queuing mechanism to pass through records in larger batches then this would result in fewer and larger ROS files.  It would work but if you wanted to take your OLTP system to be reading very close to its writing activity it would not fit the use case.

The WOS/ROS mechanism is a neat work around for the fundamental performance penalty of writes in a column store DB but fundamentally Vertica is not an OLTP DB but rather a data mart technology that can ingest data in near real time

Comment: Thx for the reply, at this point i have reached Arquitect level in Vertica ! Thx anyway

Comment: Correction here, there is no limit of 1024 containers there is a limit of 1024 partitions. I have tables that have 6500K+ ROS containers and they function just fine. The number of containers doesn't mean much until you take the design into account. We have many projections and many partitions and that makes many containers but if you have 1 partition and 1 projection then having a lot of containers will ruin your performance.

Comment: @user1084563 Incorrect.  The ROS limit is not on a table, but rather on each projection per node. Partitioning dictates the granularity of these ROS containers, and therefore can cause many ROS containers if you are not careful, and ROS pushback if you exceed the limit.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are different ways to read into this question.

1. Can you use Vertica as an OLTP database?

First I'll define this question a bit. An OLTP database means the database itself is responsible for the transaction processing, not simply receiving somewhat normalized data.

My answer here is absolutely not, unless perhaps it is a single user database. There is practically no RI, no RI locking, table locks on DELETE/UPDATE, and you're likely to accumulate a delete vector in normal OLTP type usage.

You can work around some of these with some extensive middleware programming (distributed locks, heavy avoidance of DELETE/UPDATE, etc).  But why? There are tons of options out there that are not Oracle, don't carry a huge price tag but give you everything you need for OLTP.

2. Can you use Vertica to ingest and query OLTP data?

Yes, definitely. Best to use Vertica towards its strengths, though. Queries in Vertica tend to have a fair amount of overhead, and you can plow through large amounts of data with ease, even normalized.  I would not be using Vertica to primary run point queries, grabbing a few rows here and there.  It isn't that you can't, but you can't with the same concurrency as other databases that are meant for this purpose.

TL;DR Use the right tool for the right job. I really love using Vertica, but just because I like to swing a hammer doesn't mean that every problem is a nail.

Comment: Very well put ! Thx for the great post.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little old now but i'll share my experience.

I would not suggest vertica as OLTP unless you very carefully consider your workload.

As mentioned in other answers, Vertica has 2 types of storage. ROS is the Read Optimized Storage and WOS is the Write Optimized Storage. WOS is purely in memory so it performs better for inserts but queries slower as all the small updates need to be queried and unioned. Vertica can handle small loads in theory but in practice it didn't work out very well for us performance wise. Also there are drawbacks to WOS namely being that when the database fails WOS is not necessarily preserved when it rolls back to last good epoch. (ROS isn't either but in practice you lose a lot less from ROS).

ROS is a lot more reliable and gives better read performance but you will never be able to handle more than a certain number of queries without a careful design. Although vertica is horizontally scalable, in practice large tables get segmented across all nodes and therefore queries must run on all nodes. So adding more nodes doesn't mean handling more concurrent queries it just means less work per query. If your tables are small enough to be unsegmented then this might not be an issue for you.

Also worth noting is the OLTP typically implies lots concurrent transactions so you'll need to plan resource pools very carefully. By default vertica has a planned concurrency for the general resource pool of the minimum of number of cores per server or RAM/2GB. Essentially what this value does is determine the default memory allocation PER NODE for a segmented query. Therefore by default vertica will not let you run more queries than cores. You can adjust this value but once you hit a cap on memory theres no much you can do because the memory is allocated per node so adding more nodes doesn't even help. If you hit any errors at all for resource pool memory allocations that is the first config your should look at.

Additionally, Vertica is bad with deletes and updates (which resolve to a delete and an insert in the background) so if these are a regular part of your workload then Vertica is probably a bad choice. Personally we use MySQL for our dimension tables that require deletes/updates and then sync that data periodically into vertica to use for joins.

Personally I use Vertica as an OLTP-ish realtime-ish database. We batch our loads into 5 minute intervals which makes vertica happy in terms of how many/large the inserts are. These batches are inserted using COPY DIRECT so that they avoid WOS entirely (only do this if they are large batches as this forces ROS container creation and can be bad if you do it too often). As many projections as we can have are unsegmented to allow better scale out since this makes queries hit only 1 node and allocate memory on only 1 node. It has worked well for us so far and we load about 5 billion rows a day with realtime querying from our UI.

Comment: It passed some time but still your post was vary useful,time passed and i have got more into Vertica, true all you said and it's all down to "Write Once" - this trade off makes Vertica excel in some parts. but as you do it:- mixing MySQL(high trans) with this Vertica stupid fast loads :) it the way to go.

Comment: is there a way you can drop me a msg with your contact on my site http://www.aodba.com/en/about/ i have a doubt regarding automation. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Up_one - considering the telecom use-case - are you doing CDR or something else?

To answer your original question yes Vertica may be a great fit but it depends on how you are loading the data, how you are doing updates, what your data size is and what your SLA is.  I am really familiar in this space because I implemented Vertica at a telecom that I worked for at the time.

Comment: What tools do you use to load the data ?